# no instance of overloaded function "" matches the argument list error

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm Getting the following errors in my cpp and I'm not quite sure how to fix them (I'm new to C++)

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::compare [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list    KernelHop   c:\Users\Root\Downloads\KernelHop-master (1)\KernelHop-master\KernelHop\KernelHop.cpp   102 


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::compare [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list    KernelHop   c:\Users\Root\Downloads\KernelHop-master (1)\KernelHop-master\KernelHop\KernelHop.cpp   110
```

My Code:

```
DWORD FindProcessId(const std::string processName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
    processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

    HANDLE processSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (processSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    Process32First(processSnapshot, &processInfo);
    if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
    {
        CloseHandle(processSnapshot);
        return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
    }

    while (Process32Next(processSnapshot, &processInfo))
    {
        if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
        {
            CloseHandle(processSnapshot);
            return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(processSnapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: BTW the errors happen at !processName.compare

Comment: Most likely your application is build in UNICODE mode. Check this.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably compiling as Unicode, in which case `PROCESSENTRY32::szExeFile` will be a wide string (`wchar_t[]`), but `std::string::compare()` expects a byte string (`char[]`). So try using `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: This fixxed 2 errors and cause a new one :/ where would i check if my app is unicode in VS 2015 ?

Comment: In the Solution Explorer pane, right-click your project and go to **Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set**. But note that Unicode is the recommended option (as opposed to MBCS a.k.a ANSI). What's the new error you're getting?

Comment: Note that this only affects `TCHAR`-based APIs, which map to either Ansi or Unicode based on your configuration settings. If you call the Ansi or Unicode APIs directly instead, this does not apply at all. Use `std::string` with `char`-based APIs, and `std::wstring` with `wchar_t`-based APIs.  So, in the OP's example, either 1) change the `std::string` to `std::wstring` and use the `W` variant of API calls, or 2) change the `std::string` to `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` instead, and leave the rest of the code as-is.

Comment: Here is the new error @user1610015 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [9]" to "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>" KernelHop c:\Users\Root\Downloads\KernelHop-master\KernelHop-master\KernelHop\KernelHop.cpp 150

Comment: @FelixSnow I'm guessing that error is in the call to FindProcessId. So again just use a wide string instead. Basically go through your code and replace every `char` with `WCHAR`, every `std::string` with `std::wstring`, and every string literal (like `"stuff"`) with a wide string literal (like `L"stuff"`).